# Newton Json not parsing with bullet characters in the string

Tags: c#, json, json.net

The Json file I have got few bullet characters due to which it is not parsing. I tried different ways to replace the bullet characters but no success. Help please. Thanks.

Json file content is below

`"items": [ { "type": 202, "path": "C\TestFile.json", "name": "   •   OptionA?" }]`

I tried following with no success.

option 1:
`System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\\Users\\xxx\\Files\\JsonTestFile.txt").Replace(@"\\u2022",string.Empty)`

option 2:
`System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(strFileContent, "[\\u2022,\\u2023,\\u25E6,\\u2043,\\u2219]\\s\\d", " ");`

option 3: converted the file to UTF-8 in notepad++ and tried parsing but it still fails.

Comment: is that your whole JSON-file? because it's invalid. (but not because of the bullet point). a) you can't start with a key, you need to wrap it in an object `{}`, and b) you gotta escape that `\`

Comment: if your problem is only about replacing a • with whitespace and not building a c# program to do this you can try an online solution like this one: https://www.browserling.com/tools/text-replace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{"items": [ { "type": 202, "path": "C\TestFile.json", "name": "   •   OptionA?" }]}
```

Above is the correct json but it will not compile because of the value you have for "path".

You have to escape the backslash with another \.. Following deserializes correctly.

```
{ "items": [ { "type": 202, "path": "C:\\TestFile.json", "name": "   •   OptionA?" }] }

Console.WriteLine(JObject.Parse(json)["items"][0]["path"].ToString());

//prints
C:\\TestFile.Json
```